# MySQL vs. static HTML pages

Tags: php, mysql, html, static

I'm working on a big internet project. I'm writing code in PHP, and I need some advice.

My website has both dynamic and static pages. The dynamic pages get contents from a MySQL DB. But I want to put the contents of the static pages into the MySQL DB tables too. Is it a good idea? Please explain me pros and cons if you think that it's not good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pros: you can write your own content management system. Cons: one million people before you wrote a content management system in PHP, and a lot of them are bound to be better at it than you. So if you want this, for starters check out how (not whether ;-)) to integrate an existing PHP CMS.

Static pages in the database are fine, as long as you're aware that they will have more processing overhead for a request than a pure static page served e.g. directly from Apache. However, it's usually easy to fix this by putting a caching proxy in front of your database-stored static pages - as long as you make sure to put the correct cache-control headers on all responses, it's quite simple to setup.

Answer (score 1):

Many sites change on their server, this means they change dynamically made pages to static ones.

A dynamic page uses more of the server than a static page will. In other words - more static pages less load on server, because it doesn't need to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot or projects work hard into creating cache systems to put dynamic contents into static caches. This is a self explanatory answer. Accessing a file cache is faster than rendering dynamic contents, so instead of putting everything in a database, why don't you try to exact opposite? This does not mean to have a static web site and drop the database altogether, but rather keep a balance between static and dynamic content and use cached data as much as possible.